# Load all fields for a specific ListItem using CSOM

Tags: 2013, 2010, client-object-model, list-item, csom

I want to load all FieldValues for a specific ListItem

ForExample

```
  public ListItem GetItemById(List SPList, int id, string[] fieldNames)
        {
            using (Ctx)
            {
                ListItem item = SPList.GetItemById(id);
                if (fieldNames != null)
                {
                    foreach (string field in fieldNames)
                    {
                        Ctx.Load(item, i => i[field]);
                    }                   
                } 
                //Tried below line, doesn't work
                //Ctx.Load(item, i => i.FieldValues);            
                Ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                return item;
            }
```

So in above example i am passing the field names to load, however i want all fields to be loaded.

Answer (score 4):

None of the existing answers worked for me. This does:

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = string.Format("<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", itemId);
ListItemCollection collListItem = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
clientContext.Load(collListItem);
clientContext.Load(collListItem,
      items => items.Include(
          item => item.Id,
          item => item.DisplayName,
          item => item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments,
          item => item.Folder,
          item => item.File,
          item => item.ContentType
          ));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

...

Comment: that would work if it was my answer ;)

Comment: Why are you loading `collListItem` twice?

Comment: i believe that is a typo. but i don't have an environment handy to test if that's true or not.

Comment: I dont think it is a typo, because the first line loads all fields, the second one just the "included" ones

Answer (score 2):

According to my research, List.GetItemById will naturally return all the fields of the item as well as their values, while other methods of getting a list item will not.

For example: [List.GetItemById Will Return Item with All Fields](http://ethan-deng.blogspot.com/2013/03/list.html)

Comment: No it doesn't load all values

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var item = list.GetItemById(id);
                _context.Load(item);
            _context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: No field values are loaded this way.

Answer (score 0):

The following CSOM worked from my desktop. Change parameter as needed...

Import-Module ‘C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\SharePoint Client\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll’

```
$site = 'https://inside.nov.com/mfg/QC'
$context = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)
$context.Credentials = $credentials
$list = $context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle('Report Issues')
$ListItems = $List.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery()) 
$Context.Load($ListItems)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()    


write-host "Total Number of List Items found:"$ListItems.Count

# get required fields from this list

$fields = $list.Fields
$Context.Load($fields)
$Context.ExecuteQuery() 

foreach ($field in $fields)
{
    if($field.Required -eq $true)
    {
       write-host $field.Title
       #write-host $field.InternalName
       #write-host $field.StaticName
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not appear to load the fields and values of the specified list item, which is what was requested.

Answer (score 0):

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"FSObjType\" /><Value Type=\"Integer\">0</Value></Eq></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
ListItemCollection listItemCollection = srcList.GetItems(camlQuery);
srcContext.Load(listItemCollection);
await srcContext.ExecuteQueryAsync();
```

Querying for FSObjType=0 returns all items with all fields populated! See:
https://blog.velingeorgiev.com/sharepoint-online-csom-all-list-items-content-caml-query

The query gets all list items. May you just could add an AND clause to the query to get a specific item.

Answer (score -2):

One should try following code

```
var item = list.GetItemById(id);
spContext.Load(item);
spContext.Load(item.Fields);
spContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

This will load all the fields of the given list item.

Comment: It seems that a list item in this context does not have a Fields collection so it can't be loaded this way.