# Get all content and child content inside a folder using sharepoint PNP framework

Tags: development, document-library, csom, folder, pnp

I can get all contents inside a SharePoint list like this:

```
List list = oWebsite.Lists.GetByTitle("Documents");
ListItemCollection Items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
```

This works fine, But now I want to get all the contents of a folder (not list). How can I achieve this?

```
FolderCollection folCol = list.RootFolder.Folders;
var myFolder = folCol.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "my folder name");
```

I want to find all the content (child folder, child files, child folders and files inside child folders too) inside `myFolder`

Comment: Try with `<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\">` in CAML query as mentioned [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/149452/load-all-fields-for-a-specific-listitem-using-csom/289231)

Comment: @GaneshSanap that thread talks about lretrieving items inside a list, Here I want items isnside a folder

Answer (score 1):

Alternative 1:

```
         Folder folder = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(web.ServerRelativeUrl + "/MyRecordLibrary/Folder1/");
         clientContext.Load(folder);
         clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

         CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
         camlQuery.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='Recursive'>
                                 <Query>
                                 </Query>
                             </View>";
         camlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl = folder.ServerRelativeUrl;
         ListItemCollection listItems = list.GetItems(camlQuery);
         clientContext.Load(listItems);
         clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Alternative 2:

```
    camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"> " +
                "<Query>" +
                "<Where>" +
                            "<Eq>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name=\"FileDirRef\" />" +
                                "<Value Type=\"Text\">lib/Folder/Folder</Value>" + // I am not sure if you need an address relative to the document library or the site
                             "</Eq>" +
                "</Where>" +
                "</Query>" +
                "</View>";
```